# Changes bases with drug elimination - exponential decay

Tags: calculus

I keep getting stuck on this problem. I have an exponential decay equation that says
$$A = 120(0.88)^t$$

and can't figure out how this can be converted to 
$$y = 120e^{-0.128x}$$

I know we are using the natural log somewhere but can't see where. 
Any advice? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, is it just as simple as taking ln(0.88) = -0.1278 ? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a basic property of exponents and logarithms, for any number $b>0$: $\color{red}{b=e^{\ln b}}$.

Now apply this to $b=0.88$.

Comment: Thank u! I don't know why that kept stumping me!